# Cant play HTML Audio on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, webrtc, audio-streaming, peer

i have a Webapplication where users can talk to each other via Webrtc and a peer Server.
My Problem is, that on a ios devices i cant send my audio and i cant hear the others.
After a little bit research, i found out, that its a intentional behavior from apple. A audio can only played, if the audio is triggered by a user and not from the website.
But my application is a random lobby where people can talk to each other and switch the the "partner" by click on the button. After the click its search for another free user and than both are connected via the peer and share their audio stream.

Than i tried to call audio.play() on a touch event. But that didn't work either. Nothing happend. Still no voice on both sides. Do you guys know, how can or should i handle this problem.

On Browser all works fine. This problem does only appears on IOS Mobile Browsers.

King regards.

Comment: Are you saying you want to preload or autoplay audio files on iOS devices? Because if so, then I don't know if there's a good way around it. You might consider building an application with React Native or Electron, both of which allow you to develop mobile applications using JavaScript.

Comment: Hey, its like this: User1 klicks a button and searching for a User2 who is also searching a partner to make a voicecall. And when User1 found User2 they share their audio stream with each other so they can hear each other (via webrtc and peer). If one of the user clicks the button again, he will connect with a another user for a voicecall. And everytime a user connects to another user, they have to share their audio stream, which i bind into a audio html element. And iam using angular.

Comment: So I click a button to search for someone to set up a voicecall with, and you tap that same button. We find each other and then are connected to an audio stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of outputting directly from your media elements, consider using the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API).  Specifically:

1. Create an [AudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext)/[webkitAudioContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/PlayingandSynthesizingSounds/PlayingandSynthesizingSounds.html).  It will usually start out "suspended".
2. On user interaction, such as an initial click, call `context.resume()`.
3. When you want to output audio from a new WebRTC stream, create a new [MediaStreamAudioSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamAudioSourceNode/mediaStream), and connect it to your audio graph.  (e.g. `mediaStreamNode.connect(context.destination)`)

This isn't a hack or workaround the autoplay restrictions in any way.  It's simply putting all of your audio outputs in one place.

Answer (score -1):

You are essentially asking how to bypass a restriction. You haven't specified exactly which restriction you're trying to bypass, though, so I can only assume based on what you've told me thus far that you're trying to autoplay audio.

If this is the case, the easiest thing to do would possibly be to set up a blank video stream instead of an audio stream, and add the autoplay property like so:

```
<video autoplay>
```

However, **don't count on this workaround - or ANY workaround for ANY restriction - working as a long-term solution,** if you can even get it to work today. If you can bypass a restriction, so can less scrupulous developers, so Apple may be inclined to patch any method of bypassing their restrictions. Your best bet is probably to use React Native to build a native application for iOS and Android. React Native can use either JavaScript or TypeScript (you choose which).

Comment: Hey thanks for you reply. I wrote above that iam using angular. 
I want to build later an cordova application with my angular project for ios and android. Does i understand you right, that with an cordova project, this problem what i have does not exist?